# Make eclipse pdt default editor for php, css etc. files in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse php recently. When i want to open a css or php file it doesn't show option for eclipse, not even in the other applications list.

I want to set Eclipse as my default editor to handle such kind of files.